# SQL: Increment column value foreach id (loop?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

that I made into a big stored-procedure to do a pivot in the end. 
What I want to do is fill the 'index' column like an identity column BUT it must re-start from '1' on each ID like

[image: this].

I think it must be some kind of foreach(id)

PS: the ID are not always 3.. it's for the example.

Comment: Please don't provide images of data, we can't consume it. Take the time to provide the data as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ROW_NUMBER() with PARTITION BY would seem like a good method to create your Index column.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID 
    , [Time]
    , IDx
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID
           ORDER BY IDx ASC) AS "Index"
FROM
    myTable;
```